# Como utilizar uma função para preencher todas as posições do vetor alocado dinamicamente?

Tags: c, array, matriz, ponteiro, alocação

Boa tarde pessoal, estou vendo pela primeira vez a linguagem C e não estou conseguindo progredir em um trabalho.

Primeiro é solicitado que crie uma função int receberInteiro() Esta função vai solicitar a digitação de um número inteiro e positivo, validá-lo, para que não seja digitado incorretamente, e, após a validação, retornar o número para quem solicitou. Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
  int receberInteiro() {

int num;

 setbuf(stdout,NULL);

   do 
   {

      printf("Informe um numero inteiro (Não é aceito numero negativo):");
      scanf("%d", &num);


   }while (num < 0);

 return num;
}
```

Em seguida é solicitado que crie uma segunda função sendo ela preencherVetor(int *vetor, int tamanho);

Esta função vai preencher todas as posições do vetor alocado dinamicamente - utilizar a função 01 para este preenchimento. Ao final retorne  a soma dos elementos.

Nesse momento que estou preso, pois não sei como faz para usar o que o usuário digitou na primeira função para preencher todas as posições do vetor alocado dinamicamente.

Isso porque a terceira função seria void alocarVetor(int *somaTotal)

e ela iria solicitar o tamanho do vetor ao usuário (faça a chamada da função 01 para preencher este item) em seguida declarar um ponteiro inteiro, que receberá a alocação, depois alocar o vetor, do tamanho indicado pelo usuário, conforme item a, para dentro do ponteiro do item b. E por fim executar a função 02 para preencher as posições do vetor alocado.O valor retornado pela função 02 será enviado, via parâmetro por referência, para quem solicitou a função 03.

Como fiquei travado na 2 não sei por onde começar na 3.

Answer (score 0):

A segunda função é:

```
int preencherVetor(int *vetor, int tamanho) {
    int i, soma=0;
    vetor = (int *) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));
    for (i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        vetor[i] = receberInteiro();
        soma += vetor[i];
    }
    return soma;
}
```